# Recording screen and user inputs (gestures) on iPad

Tags: ipad, video, screen, recording

I need to perform an usability study of my application running on an iPad and would like to **record the screen** (video showing what is going on) as well as **gestures** (where and when users tap their fingers on screen).

Tools like Quicktime Player X, Camtasia or ScreenFlow can record the screen video, but not gestures.

Do you know any solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can program your app so that it shows the gestures on screen - then it would appear in the recorded video as well. You would then have a simple switch in your program's source code so that you can enable this feature only for demonstration videos and not in the actual released app.

Many modules exist for doing this easily - for example:

- [Swift: TouchVisualizer](https://github.com/morizotter/TouchVisualizer)
- [Obj-C + Swift: COSTouchVisualizer](https://github.com/conopsys/COSTouchVisualizer)
- [Obj-C + Swift: Touchpose](https://github.com/toddreed/Touchpose)
- [Obj-C + Swift: Fingertips](https://github.com/mapbox/Fingertips)

A less sophisticated solution is to use the built-in accessibility features of iOS. You can read a guide on doing that [here](http://www.techgrapple.com/record-iphone-ios-screen-showing-touches-tap-signs/).

Comment: Thank you Patrix for this great suggestion, however I actually cannot change the visual look of the app. I am not doing a "demonstration video", I do a usability study with real people, who should not be confused with showing gestures on the screen. It is necessary that they experience the original product.

Comment: The suggestion was actually from me, not patrix. You cannot with conventional software record something different from what the user sees on screen. What you need to do is then to add code to your app that logs every touch to a logfile or over the network. Using the timestamps in that log you can create a small Mac/PC program that adds your own overlay graphics to the recorded video at the logged coordinates.

Comment: Thank you again for the suggestion. Yes, it seems, like I don`t have any other option, than extra programming effort :) (and sorry for thanking a wrong person before, Jksoegaard :))